# Adding table row <tr> into a table using .each (underscore)

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Using underscore templates, I am trying to create a calendar . I want to put each day in its own `<td></td>` and after 7 days, insert a table row `<tr></tr>`. So that 7 days will appear in 1 row like a week.

Example of what I am trying to achieve

```html
<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th>Monday</th> 
        <th>Tuesday</th> 
        <th>Wednesday</th> 
        <th>Thursday</th> 
        <th>Friday</th> 
        <th>Saturday</th> 
        <th>Sunday</th> 
    </tr> 
    </thead>  
    <tr>
        <td>1th</td><td>2nd</td><td>3rd</td><td>4th</td><td>5th</td><td>6th</td><td>7th</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8th</td><td>9th</td><td>10th</td><td>11th</td><td>12th</td><td>13th</td><td>14th</td>
    </tr>
    // through to 35 days 
</table>
```

In an underscore template I am using the .each to loop and display a list of days that comes from an api. I have made this sad attempt to use the index if it is a multiple of 7, and then add a `<tr>` but as expected, the table was broken. He’s my attempt

```html
    <table> 
        <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Monday</th> 
            <th>Tuesday</th> 
            <th>Wednesday</th> 
            <th>Thursday</th> 
            <th>Friday</th> 
            <th>Saturday</th> 
            <th>Sunday</th> 
        </tr> 
        </thead>  
        <% _.each(allDaysData, function(item, index){ %> 
        <% if ( index == 6 || index == 13 || index == 20 || index == 27) { %> <tr>  <% } %> 
            <td >     <%= allDaysData.day %>     </td> 
            <% if ( index == 6 || index == 13 || index == 20 || index == 27) { %> </tr>
        <% } %>         <% }) %> 
    </table>
```

Could anyone tell me how to do this properly? Hopefully I have given enough information of what I am trying to do. If not I can add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know underscore.js but this looks fine for me.

```html
<tr>
<% _.each(allDaysData, function(item, index){ %> 
<td> <%= item.day %> </td> 
<% if ((index + 1) % 7 == 0) { %> </tr><tr>  <% } %> 
<% }) %> 
</tr>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I tried the code but is wrapping the 1st 6 table datas in a table row, and then then every 7th table data in its own table row. Here is the output - http://plnkr.co/edit/HKrnaVLtnnRpWjwpFFIX?p=info

Comment: @Josethehose I didn't looked for purpose of these if's. I've just edited my answer - it's working now :)

Answer (score 0):

consider using `%` (modulo) operator. What you achieve is to run `if` callback only if processing every 7-th element.

so in your example instead of explicit declarations of `index == 6, index == 13, ...`

you may use

`if((index + 1) % 7 === 0) { print <tr> here }`